# how to strip out \n from results returned by apk version command

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I'm running the command:

```
apk version openssh
```

The output includes \n.  It looks like this:

```
testbox:~# apk version openssh
Installed:                                Available:
openssh-6.8_p1-r5                       < 6.8_p1-r6 
testbox:~#
```

I need a way to change this output so that it looks like this:

```
     openssh-6.8_p1-r5 < 6.8_p1-r6
```

So to be explicit, I want to:

1. get rid of \n characters
2. remove all extra spaces
3. remove the headers.
4. NOT have to save to a file, but run one command to do this all at once.

Is there a way to do this?  I've been google examples of grep and I tried experimenting with it to try get rid of the \n but no success yet.

I'm still working my way through this but if you have some suggestions I'd appreciate it.

EDIT 1

I've used sed and I've got it down to this:

```
testbox:~# apk version openssh | sed 's/Installed://g'| sed 's/Available://g' | sed 's/\n//g'

openssh-6.8_p1-r5                       < 6.8_p1-r6
```

As you can see, my attempt to get rid of the newline has failed

**Edit 2**

Using "tr" to replace the newline. Getting closer. Now my command / output looks like this:

```
testbox:~# apk version openssh | sed 's/Installed://g'| sed 's/Available://g' | tr '\n' ' '
                                 openssh-6.8_p1-r5                       < 6.8_p1-r6  testbox:~#
```

Comment: `awk` or maybe even `sed` would be useful here. Maybe `| sed 's/\s+/ /`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `one command to do this all at once` you asked for is:

```
apk version openssh | awk 'NR>1{$1=$1;print}'
```

- `NR>1` skips the first (header) line
- `$1=$1` changes all chains of white space to single blank chars
- `print` prints the line

Comment: I guess you're right!  Can you step me through it a bit?

Comment: I added an explanation. I highly recommend the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins if you're going to be doing any text manipulation on UNIX.

Answer (score 1):

pipe the output to

```
... | sed 1d | tr -s ' '

openssh-6.8_p1-r5 < 6.8_p1-r6
```

`sed 1d` deletes the header line

`tr -s` squeezes chars (spaces in this case) to one instance.

Comment: ah! yours is so much more elegant!  Can you tell me what the sed 1d does?

Answer (score 0):

apk version openssh | sed 's/Installed://g'| sed 's/Available://g' | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/ *//g'